# External payment gateway integrate in magento 2

Tags: magento2

External payment gateway integrate in magento 2.
Any tutorial, link or any code please provide.
Or any Suggestion please guide

Answer (score 0):

You can google about it and would find plenty of resources about how to implement / create custom payment method module for magento.

there are 2 types of payment methods :

1 - Offline Payment methods:
like , Cash on Delivery , Bank Transfer , Pay order

2- Online Payment methods 
Credit card paymen etc.

you can read in details about how these work here ( [Magento payment provider gateway
)](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/payments-integrations/payment-gateway/payment-gateway-intro.html)
and here ( [Payment gateway integrations](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/payments-integrations/bk-payments-integrations.html)  and also you .[Download Sample Payment method](https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/magento-2-create-payment-method/) code.

Comment: I just created a sample payment method but I want to integrate tiybr payment integration in it external payment gateway. So the tiybr gateway provide me html form and javascript page so I want to integrate this form in sample payment method can u pls elaborate or give reference how

Comment: you should check how module-paypal express checkout is setup. this will give you idea how to submit form. Also, you can create a phtml file and submit with js code. ( using controller call that phtml file and post your data in there ).